# Angular JS, Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'blogger.posts.controllers' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am following the Book Angular.js - Novice to Ninja

This is how I have set up the project:
**app/js/app.js:**

```
angular.module('blogger', ['blogger.posts', 'ui.router']);
```

**app/modules/posts/postModule.js:**

```
angular.module('blogger.posts', ['blogger.posts.controllers', 'blogger.posts.services']);

angular.module('blogger.posts').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/posts');
    $stateProvider.state('allPosts', {
        url:'/posts',
        templateUrl:'modules/posts/views/posts.html',
        controller:'PostsController'
    });
}]);
```

**app/modules/posts/js/controllers.js:**

```
angular.module('blogger.posts.controllers')
    .controller('PostController', ['$scope', 'postService', function($scope, postService){
        $scope.getAllPosts=function(){
            return postService.getAll();
        };
        $scope.posts=$scope.getAllPosts();
    }]);
```

**app/modules/posts/js/services.js:**

```
angular.module('blogger.posts.services').factory('postService', 
    function(){
        return {
            posts:[{
                id:1,
                title:'Sample title 1',
                content:'Sample content 1',
                permalink:'sample-title1',
                author:'Sandy',
                datePublished:'2015-21-01'
            }],
            getAll:function(){
                return this.posts;
            }
       }
  });
```

But if I run the code it is giving me this error:

**Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'blogger.posts.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument**

Comment: In which order do you include your js files in your webpage ?

Comment: Are there any other console errors, specifically relating to **controllers.js**?

Comment: <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/postModule.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/js/services.js"></script>

Comment: Check the order in which you arranged your <Script> files, The main module i.e  "blogger" should be the last one, and all services and controllers should be first. Take app.js to the last

Comment: No it says the error that I have mentioned in the question

Comment: @BabajideFowotade I tried that too. still it s saying the same error

Comment: I think you should include js/controllers.js and then postModule.js because of trying to inject unexisting controllers module in the postModule.js

Comment: If that doesn't work, you may have to remove all the dependencies in postModule.js and place it in app.js

Comment: @BabajideFowotade If I do that then the heirarchy will be disturbed. For instance: there can be many modules like postModule which will have their own depenecies.

Comment: Okay then try to replace <script src="modules/posts/js/controllers.js"></script> <script src="modules/posts/js/services.js"></script> before postmodule.js

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question but have you checked if there is `ng-app="blogger"` in your html ?

Comment: yes @Maverick I have included that

Comment: @BabajideFowotade: same error exists. Although initially I tried removing the postModule.js and included its code inside app.js, that time it worked. So this problem is coming when I try to create a heirarchy using the postModule.js

Comment: can you replicate this on jsfiddle or plnkr.co

Comment: also try this add `angular.module('blogger.posts', []);` in app.js at the top before `module blogger`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Create blogger.posts which dependes on sub modules 
 * 'blogger.posts.controllers', 'blogger.posts.services'
 * Ex . angular.module('moduleName', []) syntax for module setter.
 *  This is requried before registering on module
 */
angular.module('blogger.posts', ['blogger.posts.controllers',
 'blogger.posts.services']);

/**
 * Module setters
 */
angular.module('blogger.posts.controllers', []);
angular.module('blogger.posts.services', []);

/**
 * Now you can register controllers , service, directive etc 
 */
angular.module('blogger.posts.services').factory('postService',
    function () {
        return {
            posts: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Sample title 1',
                content: 'Sample content 1',
                permalink: 'sample-title1',
                author: 'Sandy',
                datePublished: '2015-21-01'
            }],
            getAll: function () {
                return this.posts;
            }
        }
    });


angular.module('blogger.posts.controllers')
    .controller('PostController', ['$scope', 'postService', 
       function ($scope, postService) {
        $scope.getAllPosts = function () {
            return postService.getAll();
        };
        $scope.posts = $scope.getAllPosts();
    }]);
```

Comment: @Sandeep Rao Make sure you have included all js files

Comment: I have included all the JS files in the right order. Now I'm getting this error:Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blogger due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blogger.posts due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Comment: this error is related to the ui-router I guess. but not sure

Comment: You should inject  'ui.router' module where you are using the states

Comment: I have injected that in the app.js

Comment: angular.module('blogger.posts', ['blogger.posts.controllers', 'blogger.posts.services',  'ui.router' ]);

Comment: angular.module('blogger.posts') This is independent module and you have to resolve all dependencies.

Comment: Nah!! it didn't. still the same. but if I remove the ui-router from the app.js then it says Module "ui-router" is not available. So I'm guessing ui-router has to be in app.js

Comment: Why are you removing the dependency from any module. In your case. you have coded your app modular , in this every module will resolve its own dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this (i was doing the same tutorial :P). in the file app/js/app.js you need to have:

```
angular.module('blogger', [
   'ui.router',
   'blogger',
   'blogger.posts'
]).run(['$state', function($state){
   $state.go('allPosts');
}]);
```

and that should fix it :)